# Stopping Thread in C# while is in Unlimited wait mode

Tags: c#, multithreading

All,

I have a main thread which creates 10 threads all executing same method.
Inside this method there is a connection to a message queue and each thread waits unlimited until a message arrives. However I need to have the functionality to tell the thread to die if I wanted to. How can I do it ?

Here is an example:

```
void ExecuteThread(){
//run some stuff
//listen to a message queue
//Here wait unlimited until a message arrives
}
```

How do I notify the above code which is in the unlimited wait command to stop the thread?
I can't just abort it as I would it to gracefully disconnect from the queue.

Many Thanks,
MK

}

Comment: you say you can't abort, but if you try/catch in the thread method and catch the `ThreadAbortException`, doing cleanup there, would that not do the trick?

Comment: Which version of the .net are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Do not wait unlimited, but use WaitOne with a timeout. Put that in a loop, which checks a flag for canceling. Then, from your main thread, you can signal threads to exit.

Something like (pseudo-code):

```
while (keepRunning)
{
   //wait 5 seconds for message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What sort of message queue?  Can your main thread send a suicide message, (well, 10 suicide messages, or one suicide message with an internal count), on the queue?

Rgds,
Martin

Comment: It's cleaner, more CPU-efficient and lower-latency than continual timeouts.  You already send your thread/s messages to tell them to do stuff, so why behave differently with suicide requests?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have to create a waiting loop, which checks a shared variable. This variable says if the thread has to cancel it's operation.

WARNING: Do not create an infinity loop which checks the variable to often, this causes "busy waiting". You should wait for a message in the queue until a timeout arrives. After that timeout you can check your control variable and enter the waiting process for the queue again.